# Attempt to connect to Mi Band 2 via bluetooth

Tags: java, bluetooth

I have written the next functions

```
void getBoundedDevice() {

        mDeviceName = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
        mDeviceAddress = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        txtPhysicalAddress.setText(mDeviceAddress);

        Set<BluetoothDevice> boundedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice bd : boundedDevice) {
            if (bd.getName().contains("MI Band 2")) {
                txtPhysicalAddress.setText(bd.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }

    void initializeObjects() {
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    void initilaizeComponents() {
        btnStartConnecting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartConnecting);
        btnGetBatteryInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetBatteryInfo);
        btnWalkingInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWalkingInfo);
        btnStartVibrate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartVibrate);
        btnStopVibrate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopVibrate);
        btnGetHeartRate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetHeartRate);
        txtPhysicalAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhysicalAddress);
        txtState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtState);
        txtByte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtByte);
    }

    void initializeEvents() {
        btnStartConnecting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startConnecting();
            }
        });
        btnGetBatteryInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getBatteryStatus();
            }
        });
        btnStartVibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startVibrate();
            }
        });
        btnStopVibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopVibrate();
            }
        });
        btnGetHeartRate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startScanHeartRate();
            }
        });
    }

    void startConnecting() {

        String address = txtPhysicalAddress.getText().toString();
        bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        Log.v("test", "Connecting to " + address);
        Log.v("test", "Device name " + bluetoothDevice.getName());

        bluetoothGatt = bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(this, true, bluetoothGattCallback);

    }

    void stateConnected() {
        bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                txtState.setText("Connected");
            }
        });
    }

    void stateDisconnected() {
        bluetoothGatt.disconnect();
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                txtState.setText("Disconnected");
            }
        });
    }

    void startScanHeartRate() {
        txtByte.setText("...");
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic bchar = bluetoothGatt.getService(CustomBluetoothProfile.HeartRate.service)
                .getCharacteristic(CustomBluetoothProfile.HeartRate.controlCharacteristic);
        bchar.setValue(new byte[]{21, 2, 1});
        bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(bchar);
    }

    void listenHeartRate() {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic bchar = bluetoothGatt.getService(CustomBluetoothProfile.HeartRate.service)
                .getCharacteristic(CustomBluetoothProfile.HeartRate.measurementCharacteristic);
        bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(bchar, true);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = bchar.getDescriptor(CustomBluetoothProfile.HeartRate.descriptor);
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        isListeningHeartRate = true;
    }

    void getBatteryStatus() {
        txtByte.setText("...");
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic bchar = bluetoothGatt.getService(CustomBluetoothProfile.Basic.service)
                .getCharacteristic(CustomBluetoothProfile.Basic.batteryCharacteristic);
        if (!bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(bchar)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed get battery info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    void startVibrate() {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic bchar = bluetoothGatt.getService(CustomBluetoothProfile.AlertNotification.service)
                .getCharacteristic(CustomBluetoothProfile.AlertNotification.alertCharacteristic);
        bchar.setValue(new byte[]{2});
        if (!bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(bchar)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed start vibrate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void stopVibrate() {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic bchar = bluetoothGatt.getService(CustomBluetoothProfile.AlertNotification.service)
                .getCharacteristic(CustomBluetoothProfile.AlertNotification.alertCharacteristic);
        bchar.setValue(new byte[]{0});
        if (!bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(bchar)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed stop vibrate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    final BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            Log.v("test", "onConnectionStateChange");

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                stateConnected();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                stateDisconnected();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            Log.v("test", "onServicesDiscovered");
            listenHeartRate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            Log.v("test", "onCharacteristicRead");
            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            txtByte.setText(Arrays.toString(data));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
            Log.v("test", "onCharacteristicWrite");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            Log.v("test", "onCharacteristicChanged");
            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            txtByte.setText(Arrays.toString(data));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            super.onDescriptorRead(gatt, descriptor, status);
            Log.v("test", "onDescriptorRead");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
            Log.v("test", "onDescriptorWrite");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReliableWriteCompleted(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onReliableWriteCompleted(gatt, status);
            Log.v("test", "onReliableWriteCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
            super.onReadRemoteRssi(gatt, rssi, status);
            Log.v("test", "onReadRemoteRssi");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status) {
            super.onMtuChanged(gatt, mtu, status);
            Log.v("test", "onMtuChanged");
        }

    };
```

And to add these functions to method OnCreate();

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeObjects();
        initilaizeComponents();
        initializeEvents();

        getBoundedDevice();

    }
```

The program is connecting and working about one time, so after the Mi Band 2 is automatically disconnected and it is necessary to restart the app for working. In addition, some functions like start vibrate or stop vibrate are not working. Only the working function is start heart rate, but only for the one time (the solution is restarting the app). So the problem is instability of the working of program. How I can optimize or stable. May be I missed the main aspect